# Passing a model attribute from a jsp to controller Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm having trouble passing data inputted by a user from a jsp to a controller using a model attribute. The error returns a null pointer exception and I do not know why it's throwing this error. The code is suppose to allow a user to input data using textboxes and then save the code inputted to a repo before a database. However, the code returns a null pointer exception and I do not know why it's throwing this error.

My jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Add Paper</title>

</head>
<body>
<form:form 
action="/addResearchPapers" modelAttribute="Document">

<p>Author: </p>
<input type ="text" name="author" /> <br> 
<p>Title: </p>
<input type ="text" name="title" /> <br>
<p>Short Title: </p>
<input type ="text" name="shortTitle" /> <br>
<p>CPL: </p>
<input type ="text" name="CPL" /> <br>
<p>RBMA: </p>
<input type ="text" name="RBMA" /> <br>
<p>Editor: </p>
<input type ="text" name="editor" /> <br>
<p>Other Reps: </p>
<input type ="text" name="otherReps" /> <br>
<p>Item Type: </p>
<input type ="text" name="itemType" /> <br>
<p>Location: </p>
<input type ="text" name="location" /> <br>
<p>Language: </p>
<input type ="text" name="language" /> <br>
<p>Genre: </p>
<input type ="text" name="genre" /> 
<br><br>
<input type= "submit" value="Save Paper To Database" /> 
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller code:

```
@PostMapping("/addResearchPapers")
public String newResearchPaper(@ModelAttribute("Document") ResearchPaper Document, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

     model.addAttribute("Author", Document.getauthor());
     model.addAttribute("Title", Document.getTitle());
     model.addAttribute("Short Title", Document.getshortTitle());
     model.addAttribute("CPL", Document.getCPL()); 
     model.addAttribute("RBMA",Document.getRBMA()); 
     model.addAttribute("Editor", Document.geteditor());
     model.addAttribute("Other Reps", Document.getotherReps());
     model.addAttribute("Item Type", Document.getitemType());
     model.addAttribute("Location", Document.getlocation());
     model.addAttribute("Genre", Document.getgenre());


    RPrepo.save(model);
    return "homepage";
}
```

Comment: At which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: When I add the author to the model in the controller, it doesn't pass anything out of the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring is in picture, you must provide the path to all attributes to your bean else it will throw null pointer as it wouldn't know what you are sending and where. So in oder to overcome it, replace your

```
<input type ="text" name="author" />
```

with this:

```
<form:input type ="text" path="author" name="author" />
and so on...
```

here "path" is your field name in your ResearchPaper Bean. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Thank you. However, its now returning neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'Document' available as request attribute. DO you know how to fix this?